# How to read request headers from incoming message in a graphQL endpoint in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I have a spring boot application running with a graphql endpoint that validates and executes queries and mutations, however, I need to read one header in the incoming message in order to pass its value to another endpoint. Is there a way in graphql to read these values? some sort of getHeaders or something like that?

Comment: Depends on how do you expose GraphQL over HTTP . Do you expose it using   servlet , spring mvc or other libraries ?

Comment: i'm using the spring boot graphql starter and graphql-java-tools maven dependency, I just had to implement the GraphQLMutationResolver class

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GraphQL itself does not define any things related to how to expose it over the network , so it does not define any things related to get HTTP header.It is up to developers to use their ways.So, it depends on the underlaying technologies you use to serve GraphQL over HTTP.

Consider you use [graphql-spring-boot](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot) and `graphql-java-tools` , and assuming that you does not customize `GraphQLContext` ,  you can try to add `DataFetchingEnvironment` argument to your resolver function and then get the `GraphQLContext` from it. You can then get `HttpServletRequest` from the context and access the headers :

```java
    public Foo resolveFoo(Map<String,String> input , DataFetchingEnvironment env){

        GraphQLContext context =  env.getContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = context.getHttpServletRequest().get();
        request.getHeader("content-type");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly, this was just what I needed to do

Comment: env.getContext() returns null for me. I am using it in DataFetcher. Can you please help?

Comment: @ArjunNayak how did you solve this...

Comment: @user1912935 I used below code

final GraphQLServletContext ctx = env.getContext();
final HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getHttpServletRequest();

Comment: But as you mentioned in your earlier comment your getting null for env.getContext(), and HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getHttpServletRequest();  throws null pointer isn't it.... how did you solve null..?

Comment: How can we do this in a webflux model where we don't have access to the servlet methods? I'm having trouble applying these solutions.

Answer (score 5):

The solution by @Ken Chan was not working for me. `GraphQLContext` had no method named `getHttpServletRequest`. 
Solved it by using `GraphQLServletContext` instead. You can change the code to:

```
public Foo resolveFoo(Map<String,String> input , DataFetchingEnvironment env){

    GraphQLServletContext context =  env.getContext();
    String header = context.getHttpServletRequest().getHeader("content-type");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the type of the context is not standardized. I use SPQR, and in my case I discovered (via debug):

```java
        DefaultGlobalContext<ServletWebRequest> context = handlerParameters.getDataFetchingEnvironment().getContext();
        context.getNativeRequest().getHeader("something");
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your problem statement, but one can use a Filter to handle it before the request hits the resolver endpoints (if that's a requirement):

```
public class HeaderFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) {
    final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    
    String headerVal= httpServletRequest.getHeader("<header string>");
    
    try {
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, servletResponse);
    } catch (IOException | ServletException e) {
        //handle as you wish
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These answers are too old, for latest versions. There are two ways (1) you can try to *autowire* one HttpServletRequest in your *controller*, such as

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
public class YourQueryController {
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;
....
```

Then implement following logic to get header:

```
request.getHeader("Authorization")
```

(2) To make use of out-of-box support of `RequestContextHolder` over HTTP requests

```
ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();

val authorization = attributes.getRequest().getHeader("Authorization");
```

Comment: If you use this method with an Autowired request then how do you test the controller in a unit test as if you test like this?:
GraphQlTester.Response response = tester.document(Files.read(searchQuery, UTF_8).execute();
It will fall over as there is no autowired request in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Google brought me this answer and unfortunately it was for Spring framework. Many use Spring framework but if you use Apache Tomcat with GraphQL integration like I do, you can do use this.

```
        graphql.kickstart.servlet.context.DefaultGraphQLServletContext.DefaultGraphQLServletContext context =  dataFetchingEnvironment.getContext();
        jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request = context.getHttpServletRequest();
        String tokenBearer = request.getHeader("Authorization");
```

hth